# Sync git with bitnami/wordpress using Argo CD

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, cloud, bitnami, argocd

I just installed bitnami/wordpress image using Argo CD with Helm option. Now my deployment is synced with helm. Can I now for example sync it with my git repository? I mean to push current Wordpress files to git and sync with it? Because then I can modify plugin files what I need. Bitnami/wordpress is non-root container so I can't create sftp account.

How to do it?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want put in the git repo? How did you passed the wordpress files to your helm chart?

Comment: @EmruzHossain I used ready helm chart bitnami/wordpress. I want to update files in wp-content dir using git repository.

Comment: Did you mount any volume in `wp-content` dir?

Comment: @EmruzHossain I didn't. I just installed bitnami/wordpress. How can I mount it exacly in this dir? All structure in ArgoCD looks like this https://imgur.com/UKslc6s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by adding a sidecar container to your WordPress container that performed the git synchronization.

To do so, you have to add the following values to your WordPress application in ArgoCD:

```yaml
sidecars:
  - name: git-sync
    image: bitnami/git:2.32.0-debian-10-r24
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -ec
      - |
        [[ -f "/opt/bitnami/scripts/git/entrypoint.sh" ]] && source "/opt/bitnami/scripts/git/entrypoint.sh"
        while true; do
            #Add here your commands to synchronize the git repository with /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content
            sleep 60
        done
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /bitnami/wordpress
        name: wordpress-data
        subPath: Wordpress
```

This will configure a secondary container in your Wordpress pod sharing the wordpress-data volume. Changes

Note: You will also need to provide the values `mariadb.auth.password`, `mariadb.auth.rootPassword` and `wordpressPassword` when performing the Application Sync in ArgoCD.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this soon.

Comment: Could you help me how to add sidecar container? Because Im using wordpress from helm repo

Comment: If anyone else is using helm charts, you'll need to create a Chart.yaml and put the wordpress helm chart as a dependency. This will allow you to include custom k8s yaml resource files.